# Improving suggestion accuracy with machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, recommender-system

We have a system in which we offer users a selection of items in the form of a list. Hard coded rules are ranking the items in this list.
They have to select one of these items (we don't want to model the reasons behind this choice).
We record the position of the items for each list displayed and we record which item is selected each time.

So for ex our dataset looks like

```
Time                  item_selected   position_in_list
23/03/2017 08:17:21   1023            3
23/03/2017 08:21:03   1010            6
23/03/2017 08:21:10   1023            7
```

We also have the possibility to record the positions of non selected items, we would then change the structure of the tables to store the position of the id of the display, the item id, the selection status.

Our goal is to improve the accuracy of our ranking system so that after a while most of the users click on the first item shown in the list.

I was thinking of using a model-based collaborative filtering as in [this tutorial from Google.](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/recommendations-using-machine-learning-on-compute-engine)

The goal is that the system learn over time thanks to the users actions.

Is there a better way to achieve this result tham model-based collaborative filtering?